How can I make a feature using Python PyQt6 that is able to both take markdown inputs and display rendered (if thats the correct word) output?
I am trying to make a simple markdown editor, I am fairly new to Python, and I am using PyQt6, and trying to make a markdown editor that rather than having 1 part of the window to show the markdown text and the other part to show the rendered. The TextEdit widget is able to take inputs, and also display the rendered output of all lines other than the one being edited, something like how obsidainMD does it.
This was the code I was trying, It was a simple bit of code that would change the widget when it took text input but now it is changing each time I enter a letter, and I need to manually change it back, which isn't something that I want.
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# This isn't live view but the stakcable widgets might be something that we can use 

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        self.markdown_editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.markdown_viewer = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)

        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.markdown_editor)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.markdown_viewer)

        foo_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&FooMenu")
        self.edit_action = foo_menu.addAction("&Edit")
        self.edit_action.setCheckable(True)
        self.edit_action.triggered.connect(self.handle_edit_mode)
        self.text_updated()

    def handle_edit_mode(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(
            self.markdown_viewer
            if self.edit_action.isChecked()
            else self.markdown_editor
        )
        if self.stacked_widget.currentWidget() == self.markdown_viewer:
            self.markdown_viewer.setMarkdown(self.markdown_editor.toPlainText())
    def switch(self):
        print("Function switch run")
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.markdown_viewer)
        self.edit_action.setChecked(False)
        
    def text_updated(self):
        self.markdown_editor.textChanged.connect(self.switch)
        print("Text updated")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())```



As already explained in the current answer you're fundamentally switching on the second page every time the contents of the first are changed, which is obviously pointless. Note that while it's not impossible to do a "WYSIWYG" (What You See Is What You Get) editor in Qt, it cannot be done just by connecting the textChanged signal, and for many reasons: 1. if you attempt to use setMarkDown() on the same widget, you'll end up with recursion; 2. that would always clear the undo/redo history; 3. it doesn't consider nested and fenced tags while editing.

The only way to achieve something like this is by using the QTextDocument and QTextCursor API (see the docs), with a robust editing "buffer" that considers what is being typed and interfaces with the document structure and formats. That's why most standard markdown capable editors have two views (markdown syntax and preview): making an embedded "live preview" editor is much more complex, difficult to achieve, and hard to maintain.

@musicamante I see, thanks a lot :D. Would there be any workaround that allows me to only have one view, which is "live preview"?

No, there are no workarounds. Either use two views (switchable, or side by side, that's your choice) or go through long and patient studying of the documentation mentioned above. You want to do advanced stuff, and rich text management is quite complex, there are no workarounds to studying and experience.
